# Get latest version of Maven repository with a REST GET

Tags: maven

I'd like to keep in a single Web page all latest releases of some APIs available on Maven.

For example:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbpm/jbpm-kie-services

I'd like to display in the page:
Kie Services: latest version 7.63.0.Final

I could parse the HTML content and find which is the latest version. On the other hand, I wonder if a simpler solution exists. Is it possible, with some query parameters, to capture this information?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

#### [Maven Central (REST) API](https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/)!

e.g.:

```
curl https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:"com.google.inject"&rows=20&wt=json
```

Gives us:

> Search for all artifacts in the groupId "com.google.inject." For each artifact, returns details for the most recent version released.

For org.jbpm:jbpm-kie-services (latest version):

```
curl https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:"org.jbpm"+AND+a:"jbpm-kie-services"&wt=json
```

Returns (un-indented, un-commented):

```json
{
  "responseHeader": {...
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [{
        "id": "org.jbpm:jbpm-kie-services",
        "g": "org.jbpm",
        "a": "jbpm-kie-services",
        "latestVersion": "7.63.0.Final", // !!!
        "repositoryId": "central",...
      }]
  },...
}
```